# How to Format Input as Currency and Save as Integer in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

[image]

Good night from Indonesia, help me, please. i am creating an input display with currency format but when i save it, the input data is 0. What is the correct way to format the currency input and save it as an integer ? the following is the code that I have made.

**Blade**

```php
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="required"><b>Harga</b></label>
   <input type="text" name="harga" id="harga" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Harga" />
</div>
```

```js
<script>
var harga = document.getElementById('harga');
harga.addEventListener('keyup', function(e)
{
    harga.value = formatRupiah(this.value, 'Rp. ');
});

function formatRupiah(angka, prefix)
{
    var number_string = angka.replace(/[^,\d]/g, '').toString(),
        split    = number_string.split(','),
        sisa     = split[0].length % 3,
        rupiah     = split[0].substr(0, sisa),
        ribuan     = split[0].substr(sisa).match(/\d{3}/gi);
        
    if (ribuan) {
        separator = sisa ? '.' : '';
        rupiah += separator + ribuan.join('.');
    }
    
    rupiah = split[1] != undefined ? rupiah + ',' + split[1] : rupiah;
    return prefix == undefined ? rupiah : (rupiah ? 'Rp. ' + rupiah : '');
}
</script>
```

**Controller**

```php
    public function tambahScript(Request $request)
    {
        try{
            $img = $request['photo'];
            if (!$img == null) {
                $filename = time() . $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $img->storeAs('/photoScript', $filename, 'photoScript');
            } else {
                $filename = "blank.png";
            }

            $impld = implode("," ,$request->input('payment_id'));

            $script = Script::create([
                'user_id' => $request->user_id,
                'script_name' => $request->script_name,
                'product_name' => $request->product_name,
                'market_target' => $request->market_target,
                'payment_id' => $impld,
                'photo' =>$filename,
                'category' => $request->category,
                'harga' => $request->harga
            ]);   
            return response()->json([
                'status' => '200',
                'message' => 'Success add script',
                'data' => $script,
            ], 200);
        }catch(Exception $err){
            return response()->json([
                'status' => '500',
                'error' => $err->getMessage()
            ], 500);
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Not totally clear, but I think you will have to remove the `'Rp. '` from the `$request->harga` and remove the `.` thousands seperator before passing it to the `create` I am assuming the `harga` column in the database is defined as INT

Comment: these are many currency formatter used with input and then you can remove special characters from input value when saving in the database.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes that's what i mean. how to make it like that?

Comment: HINT: I would probably start by trying `str_replace()` before attempting anything more sexy

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly, now i know it. in controller I can use \Str::replace(['Rp. ','.'],"",$request->harga) or \Str::replace(['Rp. ','.'],"",$request->price)

Comment: Seems like a waste of time adding it in to only then remove it. Look at @BuddyCoder suggestion to move at least the `'Rp. '` into a span at the front of the field rather than maintain it inside the field

Answer (score 2):

Other things are pretty on, you just need to remove `Rp.` from input field, you can put it into an addon,

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="required"><b>Harga</b></label>
   <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Rp.</span>
       <input type="text" name="harga" id="harga" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Harga" />
   </div>
</div>
```

And the other thing you can do is change your amount field (e.g harga) from `Integer` to `Decimal` so you can store decimal values too. `Integer` will hold full digits only, that in 200, with `Decimal` you can store 200.00, 200.52 etc.

and if you are using `.` DOT as thousand separator then there is no need to change your amount field (e.g harga) from `Integer` to `Decimal` just replace `.` in `Script::create`.

```
$script = Script::create([
    'user_id' => $request->user_id,
    'script_name' => $request->script_name,
    'product_name' => $request->product_name,
    'market_target' => $request->market_target,
    'payment_id' => $impld,
    'photo' =>$filename,
    'category' => $request->category,
    'harga' => str_replace('.','',$request->harga)
]);
```

Comment: I think they are using the `.` DOT as a thousands seperator, its unlikely a decimal with 3 zeros following it

Comment: Oh, sorry,  I had no idea that @HilmiHidayat is using `.` as thousand separator. Thank you @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hidden field or a variable to store the actual value in. That's something you'd find in some frameworks:

```js
var formatInput = document.getElementById('js-format-input')
var hargaValue = ''

function renderInput() {
    var template = `<div class="form-group">
   <label class="required"><b>Harga</b></label>
   <input type="hidden" name="harga" id="harga" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Harga" value="${+hargaValue}" />
   <input type="text" name="harga_format" id="harga_format" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Harga" value="${formatRupiah(hargaValue, 'Rp. ')}" autofocus />
</div>`
  formatInput.innerHTML = template
  var harga = document.getElementById('harga');
  var hargaFormatted = document.getElementById('harga_format');
  hargaFormatted.addEventListener('keyup', function(e)
  {
      hargaValue = this.value.replace('Rp. ', '')
      renderInput();
  });
  hargaFormatted.focus()
  PosEnd(hargaFormatted)
}

function formatRupiah(angka, prefix)
{
    var number_string = angka.replace(/[^,\d]/g, '').toString(),
        split    = number_string.split(','),
        sisa     = split[0].length % 3,
        rupiah     = split[0].substr(0, sisa),
        ribuan     = split[0].substr(sisa).match(/\d{3}/gi);
        
    if (ribuan) {
        separator = sisa ? '.' : '';
        rupiah += separator + ribuan.join('.');
    }
    
    rupiah = split[1] != undefined ? rupiah + ',' + split[1] : rupiah;
    return prefix == undefined ? rupiah : (rupiah ? 'Rp. ' + rupiah : '');
}        function PosEnd(end) {
            var len = end.value.length;
              
            // Mostly for Web Browsers
            if (end.setSelectionRange) {
                end.focus();
                end.setSelectionRange(len, len);
            } else if (end.createTextRange) {
                var t = end.createTextRange();
                t.collapse(true);
                t.moveEnd('character', len);
                t.moveStart('character', len);
                t.select();
            }
        }

renderInput();
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="js-format-input"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimalist send complex data like `Rp. 100.000` if you want to save it as **Integer**, reconsider send `100000` to the server for universal use,

You can use [@shaedrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7451109/shaedrich) approach for that.

but, if you still want to use first approach, try this link below

https://www.delftstack.com/howto/php/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-in-php/